Как сделать отдельные группы в socket python
Всем привет! Создаю консольный чат на python socket и хочу сделать группы.
Что бы можно было ввести номер группы и подключиться к ней. Как-то так:
Введите код группы.
user:05
Вы подключились к группе с номером 05

Как это можно реализовать на сокетах?
